# Can't locate YAML/XS.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, osx-lion, yaml

I trying to run a Perl script to read an YAML file, but I getting this error.

> `Can't locate YAML/XS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at Perl-1.pl line 3.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Perl-1.pl line 3.`

I runnung MacOS Lion.

Comment: Does `cpan YAML::XS` do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have [YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAML%3a%3aXS) installed.

I would not advise messing around with the system `perl`. See [How do I keep my own module directory?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module/library-directory%3f) in [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html) as well as [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/App%3a%3aperlbrew).